# How to convert InputStream to instance File?

Tags: java, file, inputstream

I want to convert InputStream into instance of File.
I am googling a lot but all of answers are to save InputStream as file in file system.
Thank you!

Comment: and where would you like to save it ?

Comment: Have you read [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-file-in-java/)?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi, the link gives an example of converting File to InputStream and writing InputStream to File, not what OP asked for

Comment: @sharonbn well, that's the only way the OP will have an "instance" of a `File` is by saving the content of the `InputStream` into a File and then using the reference of the file itself. There is no other way.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi, the given answer "You can't, in general" is the correct one. the tutorial is not the "closest" answer, it is simply an incorrect one with regard to what the OP has asked

Answer (score 0):

You can't, in general.

An `InputStream` is not necessarily associated with a file in the file system.  For example, it might be connected to a socket or a pipe ... or an in-memory buffer of some kind.

Even in the specific case of a `FileInputStream`, it is not possible to get hold of the file using pure Java.

- In some versions of Java (e.g. Java 7 & Java 8) a pathname *may* be recorded in the private `path` field.  If it is, then you you can use "nasty" reflection to retrieve it.
- In other versions of Java (e.g. Java 6) the `path` field does not exist.

If you do resort to doing this, your code won't work with older versions of Java, and isn't guarantee to work in future versions either.  It is a BAD idea, IMO.

Comment: The `FileInputStream` has a `path` field (atleast in Java8) - using reflection you can retrieve this. Not that I suggest doing this :)

Comment: My mistake.  I just looked at the Java 6 version of the source code.